# MPMoviePlayerController does not work in ios 5

Tags: objective-c, ios5

i have a problem while working with MPMoviePlayerController. It doesnot work in ios 5 just a black screen to show. Not even throws any exception or any error.
Here is my code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cavity" ofType:@"mov"];
NSLog(@"%@",path);
_movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
[_movieController prepareToPlay];
[_movieController setFullscreen:NO];
[_movieController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 25, 287, 213)];
[_movieController setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded];

[_movieView addSubview:_movieController.view];
[_movieController play];
```

The _movieController object has been declared in .h file but still not in working condition.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

[[mp moviePlayer] prepareToPlay];
[[mp moviePlayer] setUseApplicationAudioSession:NO];
[[mp moviePlayer] setShouldAutoplay:YES];
[[mp moviePlayer] setControlStyle:2];
[[mp moviePlayer] setRepeatMode:MPMovieRepeatModeOne];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];
```

Comment: It is not working. Its keep on showing the the loading and activity indicator. Still not playing the movie.

Comment: did u check that url in browser?

Comment: its a file. and i gave the path to that file.
   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cavity" ofType:@"mov"];
but its just showing the loading view

Comment: i think MPMoviePlayerViewController is not getting the path of your file so check path of that file.

Comment: the path is right, i have checked it twice. the same code work in ios 4.x but ceases in ios 5.